# ros_canopen interpolated position mode, time period?

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, ros-canopen

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm driving three servos in `interpolated position mode` via the `ros_canopen` package.
Everything works quite smoothly, only sometimes i get couple of `[ WARN] RPDO timeout` messages which not always (but sometimes) results in `EMCY` in the motor drivers.

I suspect, that something is wrongly set up in the `interpolation mode` (since before, when i drove the motors in `profile position mode`, i did not have the above issue).

There are two parameters, namely `60C2sub1` and `60C2sub2` which defines the period of interpolation.
In my case `60C2sub2=-3`, which means that the interpolation time will be `1 ms`.

Then there is the `60C2sub1`object, which defines

*the rate in which target commands are sent by the host to the drive.*

In my case, `60C2sub1=10`, since the my `yaml` file i have `sync: interval_ms: 10`.

I want to ask, if the aforementioned parameters are set correctly?
I am communicating on `500kbps` with the drives.

Should i increase the sync? What do you recommend?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/332065/ros_canopen-interpolated-position-mode,-time-period?/) by [akosodry](https://answers.ros.org/users/35610/akosodry/) on ROS Answers with karma: 121 on 2019-08-31

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mathias Lüdtke](https://answers.ros.org/users/4094/mathias-l%C3%BCdtke/) on 2019-09-02**:
Which sync master plugin are you using? How often do you get the warning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First of all,  `[ WARN] RPDO timeout` and `60C2` are not related.

The warnings gets printed if the driver does not receive a particular PDO from one or more nodes.
The latter is the interpolation period, which is the time to keep moving after the last command.

If the interpolation time is exceeded, the motor will raise an EMCY.
I would set it to 15ms or 20ms (a little bit higher than the sync interval) to not stop the drive if the sync arrives a little bit too late.

Based on your description, I would guess that there is something wrong with the wiring or one or more connections.
(In my experience this is the most common cause for such problems.)

Another cause might be a wrong transmission type setting. I recommend transmission type 1 for all cyclic data.
Of course, there might be a bug in `ros_canopen`..

> I suspect, that something is wrongly set up in the interpolation mode (since before, when i drove the motors in profile position mode, i did not have the above issue).

Profiled position mode is less susceptible to connection / SYNC problems, because it just executes the last command and stops.

> I want to ask, if the aforementioned parameters are set correctly?

The settings are fine, but I would increase the intepolation period a little bit.

> Should i increase the sync?

Changing the sync inteval will just cover the root cause or will make it worse.

> What do you recommend?

1. Check your wiring.
2. Check the transmission type
3. Match the warning against the CAN log

---

Originally posted by [Mathias Lüdtke](https://answers.ros.org/users/4094/mathias-l%C3%BCdtke/) with karma: 1596 on 2019-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [akosodry](https://answers.ros.org/users/35610/akosodry/) on 2019-09-02**:
As always, @Mathias Lüdtke thank you for the detailed reply and help! I'm testing the things you recommended above.